# Sorting in MS Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, microsoft-excel-2016

I am sorting in MS Excel 2016.
DATA:

```
***Column***  A
***Header*** Room
***(data)*** A16
             A116
             A21
             A15
```

***Sort: Sort Warning***. I chose "Continue with the current selection" (not Expand the selection.") as this is just a test.
Sort by Column A Sort on Values  Order A to Z

```
***Output:***
A116
A15
A16
A21
```

My question is why did A116 appear first and not last?

Answer (score 1):

The `A` prefix makes those values text rather than numbers, so it is sorted from left to right as text.  The left to right sort means that, in this case, only the first three characters affect the order since all the entries are sorted before it gets to the `6` in `A116`.  `candle` comes before `cat` when sorting text.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [fixer1234’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1166062/150988#1166148): since the data contain letters,
Excel does a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort (which Excel calls “A to Z” order)
rather than a numeric sort. 
This means it treats the data as words (i.e., arbitrary strings),
even though they contain numbers. 
As a classic example,
consider the strings `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, …, `A97`, `A98`, `A99`. 
After sorting these (I suggest that you try it yourself),
`A1`-`A9` will be in the “right” order, as will `A10`-`A99` —
but `A10`-`A19` will be placed between `A1` and `A2`,
`A20`-`A29` will be placed between `A2` and `A3`, etc. 
The analogy that I like to offer is that, alphabetically,
words like “HA”, “HE”, “HI” and “HO” sort before “I”. 
This illustrates how two-digit numbers can be sorted
ahead of one-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's taken the beginning numerals in order. 11 is the "lowest" number.